# How is the law of contraposition a tautology?

Tags: logic

I recently started the study of Aristotelian logic in Math class.
I wanted to ask (as the title suggests) why the law of contraposition is a tautology. My book states that a tautology is a statement which is true for the all the values of the variables included.

I ask this because I constructed the truth table for the law, but the statement didn't satisfy the definition of a tautology. It would be much appreciated if anyone would help me understand this, thanks.

Comment: the law of contraposition is $(p\rightarrow q)\Leftrightarrow(\neg q\rightarrow\neg p)$ -- this is a tautology. check your truth table again

Comment: You have either some misconception that caused you to write the wrong truth table, or you simply made an error somewhere while filling in the table. Show your truth table in the original question and perhaps someone can give you helpful advice about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just fill in the truth table like this:

```
P | Q | P → Q |  ~Q → ~P | (P → Q) ↔ (~Q → ~P)
––|–––|–––––––|––––––––––|––––––––––––––––––––
T | T |   T   |     T    |         T
T | F |   F   |     F    |         T
F | T |   T   |     T    |         T
F | F |   T   |     T    |         T
```

As you see, these two have identical truth values, and they are *logically equivalent*. It means that `(P → Q) ↔ (~Q → ~P)` is a tautology, not `~Q → ~P`. If two things are logically equivalent, they create a tautology when in the form of a biconditional.

You might find [this link](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/math-proof/truth-tables/truth-tables.html) helpful: